# Check user authentication at page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

i have an application and a user must log-in before he/she can access pages. now once the user logs in i keep the user details in a session variable (say Session["CurrentUser"]).

now if a user tries to jump to a page directly i will check if the Session["CurrentUser"] has a value or not...if not then the user will be directed to the login page...

my problem is that i have done this or rather say written this "Checking Code" on almost all the pages.

what i want is this code to stay on a particular location and i will just access that method all the time on all the pages...now where should i write this method ??

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page and then have all your individual page classes inherit from that.  Have you looked at the built in ASP.net forms authentication techniques?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx). This will allow you to secure a section of your website, or individual pages via the web.config file and uses a cookie to handle authentication instead of you checking a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a base class which extends `Page`, then have all your pages codebehinds extend this.

A better solution would be to use the

```
Application_AuthenticateRequest
```

pseudo event in the Global.asax. You really shouldn't be using the session either, have you looked at Forms Authentication?

Comment: Hey buddy,

can your shed some more light...i would really appreciate the help...
thanks...